# Smd capacitor A4 sign identification

Tags: capacitor

:)
Is this a capacitor and if it is the sign A4 means ??![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7q0I.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

That is a capacitor.  It is a non-polarized 10nF ceramic capacitor.  Voltage rating isn't marked, but probably 50V.

[Marking codes :](http://www.iequalscdvdt.com/Markings_and_Codes.html)

[image]